# Nonconstructible sets of integers

Tags: set-theory

If $V \neq L$, i.e. if nonconstructible sets exist, does it necessarily follow that
$\omega=\lbrace 0,1,2,3, \ldots \rbrace$ has nonconstructible subsets?

Comment: In set theory $0\in\omega$ :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. It need not be the case.

Suppose we start with $V=L$ and we add a new subset of $\omega_1$ by using functions from countable subsets of $\omega_1$ into $2$. Every countable subset of $\omega_1$ (and so of $\omega$) is in the ground model, however the generic extension of the model is *not* $L$.

Comment: More generally, any forcing poset that is countably closed will not "add any new reals", that is, will not add new subsets of $\omega$.

Comment: @Carl: Indeed. This is just a very simple example which is very understandable.